# Прошу помощи с парсингом python

Tags: selenium, python-3.6, beautiful-soup

Помогите новичку. Пишу парсер, используя BeautifulSoup и Selenium. Нужно достать имя (Vasya Pupkin) и мыло. Мыло достал, с именем вожусь второй день. Вот кусок HTML, откуда дергаю:

```html
<div class="address">
   <p><strong>Address:</strong>Vasya Pupkin<br>Germany</p>
```

Вот строка name = soup.find('div', class_='address').find('p')

Если применять к ней .text, то в мой список попадает и имя и страна, причем в виде 'V', 'a', 's', 'y', 'a' и т.д. Не получается также преобразовать получаемый объект супа
в строку методом .str() и применить к строке регулярное выражение. Все время получается разбивка на отдельные символы. Может что-то с кодировкой? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить задачу вот таким образом:

```
name_string = str((soup.find('div', class_='address').find('p')))
clean_name = re.findall(r'</strong>(.*?)<', name_string, re.DOTALL)
```